# Memory Usage statistics different in free and htop

Tags: ram

When I run `free -m` on my command-line, it shows my used memory as show below. When I run `htop` the used memory shown is very low.

Why is that? Is it some other kind of representation? I am new to Linux. So I am totally blank on these stuff.

```
   total   3    used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   5863       4980        882          0        903       3025
```

htop:

```
Mem[|||||#####*****1076/586]
```

The used memory in free shows 4980MB and in htop shows 1076MB. What do they actually represent?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Main difference is htop counts cached memory and buffers into free memory, whereas free command does not. 
 That would give using free command

> 4980 - 3025 - 903 = 1052 used memory

that gives pretty close results with 1076 from htop. Difference can be explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65835/htop-reporting-much-higher-memory-usage-than-free-or-top). (That explains it on openSUSE I think on Ubuntu it will be nearly same), or if you are not running both commands at the same time.

[Here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) is explanation why buffers and cached memory is sometimes considered free.

Comment: This doesnt seem to be true anymore: In my case, according to `free`, `used - buffers/cache` is < 0 and that does not make much sense