# What is wrong with the memory usage?

Tags: ram, top, free

I can't figure out what is consuming my memory... Could anyone help me?

```
user@desktop:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8176992    6186776    1990216          0      43532    5052076
-/+ buffers/cache:    1091168    7085824
Swap:            0
```

Top, sorted by Memory (Shift+F + N + Enter)

```
top - 02:28:40 up  5:01,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.66, 1.00
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 191 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8176992k total,  6218404k used,  1958588k free,    43612k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  5061260k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                          
 2181 user      20   0 1246m 229m  55m S    0  2.9  11:42.13 compiz                                                                                                                                                                           
 7274 user      20   0 2809m 103m  57m S    0  1.3   0:12.46 chromium-browse                                                                                                                                                                  
 7370 user      20   0  689m 103m  66m S    0  1.3   0:09.88 chromium-browse                                                                                                                                                                  
 7389 user      20   0 1196m 101m  39m S    0  1.3   0:17.20 chromium-browse                                                                                                                                                                  
 2298 user      20   0 2164m  71m  17m S    0  0.9   0:26.33 dropbox                                                                                                                                                                          
 1460 root      20   0  165m  69m  26m S    1  0.9  16:39.59 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                             
 2452 user      20   0 1290m  58m  35m S    0  0.7   0:01.21 knotify4                                                                                                                                                                         
 1161 mysql     20   0  481m  56m 7156 S    0  0.7   0:07.74 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                           
 2198 user      20   0 1361m  51m  20m S    0  0.7   1:51.84 nautilus                                                                                                                                                                         
 2254 user      20   0  704m  39m  28m S    1  0.5   0:13.04 yakuake                                                                                                                                                                          
 2340 user      20   0  534m  36m  10m S    0  0.5   0:40.98 unity-panel-ser                                                                                                                                                                  
 7323 user      20   0 1115m  33m  18m S    0  0.4   0:00.32 chromium-browse                                                                                                                                                                  
 7282 user      20   0  328m  32m  25m S    0  0.4   0:00.15 chromium-browse                                                                                                                                                                  
 2424 user      20   0  600m  21m  16m S    0  0.3   0:00.62 kglobalaccel                                                                                                                                                                     
 2310 user      20   0  577m  21m  15m S    0  0.3   0:00.96 kded4
```

There are more lines (on the top output), but I simply cannot believe they sum up to the huge amount of memory taken by the system. 6GB are being used, and less than 2GB are free.

Comment: "What is wrong with the memory usage?" nothing, If you deduct cached from used... dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369466/memory-usage-statistics-different-in-free-and-htop

Comment: Rinzwind: The problem is that I'm using a memory-intensive process, and I get Out of Memory when I shouldn't. There are still plenty of cached memory when I get this error, and Ubuntu doesn't let it go so I can run my process.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium browser uses plenty of RAM memory once you keep opening new tab after tab, and you should consider using Firefox if memory usage is too high for your system. You can also consider disabling [Akonadi server and Nepomuk search plugin](http://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi#Disabling_the_Akonadi_subsystem) which are also responsible for high memory and cpu usage in a KDE environment.

Comment: 3.9%. So you might be correct but that is not the issue here.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually, using more RAM memory and less CPU is ideal for Linux. I would be glad to have the same "issue" on my system. I also noticed some memory "leaks" with **compiz**. I don't think **compiz** package is absolutely required for his system to work.

Comment: My main browser is Firefox; Chrome is the secondary. In addition, I'm pretty sure that's not the issue; even after closing Chrome the free memory is low.

Comment: Install BUM package with synaptic or in a terminal window **sudo apt-get install bum** . You can see all your startup daemons and processes after you open BUM. There is a ADVANCED button at the bottom of the BUM window which you can click to be able to see more info about those startup programs. You can uncheck anything that is useless (or suspicious) for you and APPLY the changes. Reboot and see if you have the same memory issues like before. You can revert to a previous configuration by simply checking daemons and/or processes that you unchecked before in BUM.