# free -m question

Tags: server, memory-usage

When using the free-m (see output in picture) the numbers don't add up.

Shouldn't the sum of used, free and available be the total amount of memory?

[image]

Comment: No, and this is not new & somewhat theoretical.  How do you classify memory that is currently 'free' (available for programs) but actually used *presently* as cache (to aid performance; it'll stop being cache the moment a program makes a malloc() thus it is still free too).  The decision made in the 1970s remains with us today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory Usage statistics different in free and htop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369466/memory-usage-statistics-different-in-free-and-htop)